How to implement a custom converter in Spring to create classes from the application properties?
I have a Spring Boot application where I want to create class instances from config properties.
These properties describe the custom (additional) fields an object can have. In this example an account. It allows users of this application to define what fields an object has.
An example application can be found on GitHub
The config looks like this:
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-config-converter
org.example:
  account:
    customFields:
      booleanTest:
        type: boolean
        i18nKey: "org.example.customField.boolean"
      stringTest:
        type: string
        i18nKey: "org.example.customField.string"
        minLenght: 1
        maxLenght: 3
      numberTest:
        type: number
        i18nKey: "org.example.customField.number"
        decimalDigits: 2

All custom fields always have the parameters type and i18nKey the other fields depend on the value of the type parameter.
I created a class structure that reflects this:
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account {
  private Map<String, CustomField> customFields;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomField {
  private String type;
  private String i18nKey;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomFieldNumber extends CustomField{
  private int decimalDigits;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomFieldString extends CustomField{
  private int minLength;
  private int maxLength;
}

Next I created the config bean:
@ConfigurationProperties("org.example")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomConfig {
  private Account account;
}

At last I implemented a converter:
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class CustomFieldConverter implements Converter<Map<String, CustomField>, CustomField> {

  @Override
  public CustomField convert(Map<String, CustomField> source) {
    // Here the logic to create the concrete instance based on the type would be implemented. 
    // But this method is not being called.
    CustomField customField = new CustomField();
    return customField;
  }
}

The problem is that the converter is never called. Spring reads the properties and transforms them into instances of CustomField. This means that for the type string and number the fields that are unique to these types are missing.
When I change in Account the customFields parameter from private Map<String, CustomField> customFields; to private Map<String, Map<String, Object>> customFields;, all fields are read into the config. But in this case I don't have the type safety of the CustomField class and its children.
So the question is: How do I have to change the converter that it is executed when the application starts and Spring processes the config?

Have you created a Bean from a configuration class in order to use it in your spring context?
@Configuration
public class ConverterConfig {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
  public CustomFieldConverter customFieldConverter() {
    return new CustomFieldConverter();
  }
}

It is necessary to let spring use this properties converter properly.

I enabled it using @EnableConfigurationProperties({CustomConfig.class}). In my understanding that should be enough. But please take a look at the example (https://github.com/ChristianHuff-DEV/spring-config-converter/tree/main/spring-config-converter) and point out what I might be misisng.
